# Use Structural design pattern to choose been dynamically

Tags: java, spring

I have a service that gets an URL from the user input, extracts the body content of this URL, apply CSS, and finally returns the result as a stream.

The tricky part is that I have different implementations depending on the URL, if the URL is not recognized, then a "default" implementation is used. To do so, I am using a [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to choose the correct implementation on Runtime.

```
@Component
public class HtmlToHtmlServiceFactory {

private final List<HtmlToHtmlService> services;

@Autowired
public HtmlToHtmlServiceFactory(List<HtmlToHtmlService> services) {
    this.services = services
}

public HtmlToHtmlService getHtmlToHtmlImpl(String url) {
    return services.stream()
        .filter(service -> service.supportsUrl(url))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("No service found that supports [%s]", url)));
}

}
```

However, for some reasons I **must** use [Structural Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pattern). I thought that a [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) would be the most appropriate.
Otherwise I was also thinking about a [Self Registration Pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/self-registration.html).

Also, I thought the `@PostConstruct` annotation could be useful to initialize the bean but how could I map my services using it?

**EDIT:**

I make this edit as it seems I did not explain well. I have only **one** controller that receives a multipartfile that contains a String (which is the URL of the website I want to parse)

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/website",
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> parseUrl(@RequestParam String url) throws IOException {

    InputStream parsedFile = htmlToHtmlServiceFactory.getHtmlToHtmlImpl(url).htmlToHtml(url);
    InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(parsedFile);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(inputStreamResource);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "structural pattern", and what are the reasons that your current approach is not OK?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I forgot to add the link for the structural pattern. It should be clearer now. The issue with my approach is that my default impl is always selected first as the 'supportUrl' is always true.

Comment: Is that because some URLs should match several converters, or because you have a bug in one of your implementations of `supportsUrl`?

Comment: I made an edit to the original post. I have only one controller, that will receive a multipartfile containing a String which is the URL of the website I want to parse. The issue with my filter is that I don't know how to set a generalist URL pattern. Right now, if I put a random url, the default impl will be used (which is great), but I put a URL pattern that is supposed to have a specific impl, it will still use the default impl (as the `supportsUrl` of the default impl is too generalist, and will be used in priority)

Comment: Change your `orElseThrow` to `orElse(`defaultHtmlToHtmlImpl)`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're looking for is the MVC pattern and [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc) [MVC](https://java2blog.com/spring-mvc-tutorial/). You could also look at [WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux) for asynch.

If you're talking about micro-services you should look into Spring Cloud Gateway, service registration and Discovery,and Circuit Breaker.

I would do something like the follwing.

Controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/path0")
public class HtmlToHtmlServiceFactory {

  @Autowired
  private final service1;
  @Autowired
  private final service2;

  @GetMapping("/my/path1/{var1}/more_path")
  public String getHtmlToHtmlImpl(@PathVariable("var1") VarType var1, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("attribute1", service1.doThings(var1))

    return view/url/that/you/configured
  }

  @GetMapping("/my/path2/{var1}/more_path")
  ...

  }
```

[ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice)

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

  @Autowired
  FallbackService fallbackService;

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Fallback_Service_Output> validationErrorHandler(IllegalArgumentException e){
      return ResponseEntity<>(FallbackService.fallback(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Services:

```java
@Service
public class service1{

  @Autowire
  Component1 component1;

  public SomeThing doThing(VarType var){
  // do things with domain and data accesss layers and whatever else
  }

}

@Service
public class service2{...}
```

view/url/that/you/configured.html:

```
someHTML maybe using template engine like thymeleaf or JSP
```

EDIT:

Are you talking about [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) then?

Something like this:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Service
public class ServiceX {

    public static HtmlToHtmlService supportsUrl(String url) {
        String pattern = "^http(s)?://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_!:,.]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~]";

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = r.matcher(url);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            return new HtmlToHtmlServiceImplX();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /*
    ...
     */


}
```

then  as @tgdavies suggested:

```java
public HtmlToHtmlService getHtmlToHtmlImpl(String url) {

        return HtmlToHtmlService htmlToHtmlService = services.stream()
                    .filter(service -> service.supportsUrl(url))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(new defaultHtmlToHtmlImpl());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it is not what I am looking for, as I have only one controller. I made an edit to the post, hopefully it is clearer now.